# wget is failing to get consul download from vagrant

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, consul

I am trying to create a consul cluster using vagrant and virtual box.
While trying to download consul, wget is unable to establish SSL connection.
Below are the logs from vagrant. wget is working fine for other downloads and I verified that the consul download link is working too. Curl works fine on this link too. But, weirdly if I use CURl in vagrant provision, it simply is not downloading (no logs) at all.
Can some one help me with this weird wget issue? I tried upgrading 'wget' too.

```
==> consulredis1: --2017-01-11 02:17:04--  https://releases.hashicorp.com/consul/0.6.4/consul_0.6.4_linux_amd64.zip
==> consulredis1: Resolving releases.hashicorp.com (releases.hashicorp.com)...
==> consulredis1: 151.101.65.183
==> consulredis1: ,
==> consulredis1: 151.101.129.183
==> consulredis1: ,
==> consulredis1: 151.101.193.183
==> consulredis1: , ...
==> consulredis1: Connecting to releases.hashicorp.com         (releases.hashicorp.com)|151.101.65.183|:443...
==> consulredis1: connected.
==> consulredis1: Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Here is my provisioning script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Step 1 - Get the necessary utilities and install them.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y unzip curl wget
sudo apt-get install -y make gcc build-essential
#apt-get install 

# Step 2 - Copy the init script to the /etc/init folder.
cp /vagrant/consul.conf /etc/init/consul.conf

# Step 3 - Get the Consul Zip file and extract it.  
cd /usr/local/bin
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
curl -k http://releases.hashicorp.com/consul/0.6.4/consul_0.6.4_linux_amd64.zip
unzip *.zip
rm *.zip

# Step 4 - Make the Consul directory.
sudo mkdir -p /etc/consul.d
sudo chmod a+w /etc/consul.d
sudo mkdir /var/consul

# Step 5 - Copy the server configuration.
cp $1 /etc/consul.d/config.json

# Step 6 - Start Consul
exec consul agent -config-file=/etc/consul.d/config.json
```

My Vagrantfile contents

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  config.vm.define "consulredis1" do |consulredis1|
    config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
        s.path = "provision.sh"
        s.args   = ["/vagrant/node1/config.json","/vagrant/node1/redis-cluster-1.init.conf","/vagrant/node1/redis-cluster-1.conf"]
    end
    consulredis1.vm.hostname = "consulredis1"
    consulredis1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.20.20.10"
  end
end
```

Comment: `wget --no-check-certificate "https://releases.hashicorp.com/consul/0.6.4/consul_0.6.4_linux_amd64.zip"` ?

Comment: I tried that too..It still does not work.

Comment: hum ... could you share your Vagrantfile and your provisioning script so it can be tested on my end

Comment: added my vagrantfile and provision scripts. They are pretty straightforward :(

Comment: wget to that http download link works fine from a normal ubuntu machine. I am clueless on why it fails in provision script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be issue with the distribution from "hashicorp/precise64".
I simply switched to using "ubuntu/trusty64" and wget worked fine.

```
#config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Hashicorp, the maintainer of Consul, recently changed its download servers to require TLS v1.2 exclusively:

> Fastly (who are fronting the releases.hashicorp.com) confirmed that this issue is caused by a change to the Hashicorp endpoint who recently went to support TLS v 1.2 only and removed support for earlier versions (1.0 and 1.1). Unfortunately, the current cURL and related libraries (e.g. OpenSSL) versions on our Precise containers don't support TLS v 1.2.

(notes [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7131), including someone from the Hashicorp weighing in)

It appears that the simplest fix, as noted elsewhere in this question, is to upgrade the version of Ubuntu. If you're not able to, you may be able to force wget to choose a specific TLS version (1.2):

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/consul/0.6.4/consul_0.6.4_linux_amd64.zip --secure-protocol=TLSv1_2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade some libraries (including libssl) so the best is to include a `apt-get dist-upgrade -y`)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Step 1 - Get the necessary utilities and install them.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y unzip curl wget
sudo apt-get install -y make gcc build-essential
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
#apt-get install 

# Step 2 - Copy the init script to the /etc/init folder.
cp /vagrant/consul.conf /etc/init/consul.conf

# Step 3 - Get the Consul Zip file and extract it.  
cd /usr/local/bin
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz -nc -nv
wget http://releases.hashicorp.com/consul/0.6.4/consul_0.6.4_linux_amd64.zip  -nc -nv
unzip *.zip
rm *.zip

# Step 4 - Make the Consul directory.
sudo mkdir -p /etc/consul.d
sudo chmod a+w /etc/consul.d
sudo mkdir /var/consul

# Step 5 - Copy the server configuration.
cp $1 /etc/consul.d/config.json

# Step 6 - Start Consul
exec consul agent -config-file=/etc/consul.d/config.json
```

Comment: I tried this and my console got all weird with funky characters and I can't read what's on the screen either! This gave me an idea and I changed the box to "ubunut/trusty64' and wget worked fine there. Thanks for your help!